# null assignment on MOQ proxy object

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

The assignment operation assigns `null` even if the `FPosition` object is instantiated using `new`

```
public void SetPosition(IPositionCollector aCollector_in, Vector3d aVector_in)
{
    FPosition aPosition = new FPosition
    {
        CoordinateX = aVector_in.X,
        CoordinateY = aVector_in.Y,
        CoordinateZ = aVector_in.Z
    };

    aCollector_in.Position = aPosition; // assigns null 
}
```

I'm using MOQ and `IPositionCollector` is a MOQ proxy object.

In what scerios it's is possible? Should I set some dependencies on MOQ object?

After using `SetupAllProperties` getitng following exception:

```
at Moq.MethodCall..ctor(Mock mock, Expression originalExpression, MethodInfo method, Expression[] arguments)
at Moq.MethodCallReturn`2..ctor(Mock mock, Expression originalExpression, MethodInfo method, Expression[] arguments)
at Moq.Mock.<>c__DisplayClass15`2.<SetupGet>b__14()
at Moq.PexProtector.Invoke[T](Func`1 function)
at Moq.Mock.SetupGet[T1,TProperty](Mock mock, Expression`1 expression)
at Moq.Mock`1.SetupGet[TProperty](Expression`1 expression)
```

Comment: Please include the test code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `DefaultValue` to `Mock` solved the issue.

```
aPositionCollectorMock.DefaultValue = DefaultValue.Mock;
```

and, removed call to `SetupAllProperties()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try `SetupAllProperties()`:

```
var mock = new Mock<IPositionCollector>();
mock.SetupAllProperties();
SetPosition(mock.Object, theVector);
```

Comment: Nope. exception within `SetupAllProperties`. tried setting `DefaultValue` to `Mock` and `Empty` also but still the same exception. (`IndexOutOfRange`)

Comment: IndexOutOfRange?  That's strange.  Are you sure it is coming from Moq?  Can you provide the stack trace please?  Might also need the unit test code.

Answer (score 1):

I think its part of behavior you should verify - check if correct position object assigned to collector:

```
// Arrange
var collectorMock = new Mock<IPositionCollector>();
var position = new FPosition
{
    CoordinateX = vector.X,
    CoordinateY = vector.Y,
    CoordinateZ = vector.Z
};
// Act
sut.SetPosition(collectorMock.Object, vector)
// Assert
collectorMock.VerifySet(c => c.Position = position);
```

BTW `FPosition` should implement Equals

OR if `FPosition` don't implement Equals and you don't want it to implement Equals

```
// Arrange
var collectorMock = new Mock<IPositionCollector>();
// Act
sut.SetPosition(collectorMock.Object, vector)
// Assert    
collectorMock.VerifySet(c => c.Position = It.Is<FPosition>(p => 
    p.CoordinateX == vector.X &&
    p.CoordinateY == vector.Y &&
    p.CoordinateZ == vector.Z));
```

Comment: Or without implementing equals you could just `mockObj.VerifySet(p => p.Position.x == vector.x && p.Position.y == vector.y)`